# Nodejs Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send message to specific user on nodejs, then save `socket.id` and `nickname` as username into array, then get that to send message, but I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.on('login', function (data) {
            login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
                if (success) {
                    usernames[data.username] = socket.id;
                    socket.emit('login', {result: true, id: value});
                } else {
                    socket.emit('login', {result: false});
                }
            });
        });

        socket.on('requestMoney', function (username) {
            log.info('username: ' + username);
            usernames[username].emit('message', {username: 'Hey !!'});
        });
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659864/socket-io-typeerror-cannot-read-property-emit-of-undefined

Comment: `usernames[username]` clearly isn't what you thing it is, and returns `undefined` instead, probably because the received key in the callbacks argument is wrong.

Comment: Username is not empty sir

Answer (score 1):

`usernames[username]` is undefined for the given `username`, because of one or more of the following things:

1. Your given `username` does not match a `data.username` connected yet, and/or
2. You're trying to call `emit` on an number, not a socket (`usernames[data.username] = socket.id;`), and/or
3. The `usernames` object is not in scope when you're trying to use it in the `requestMoney` event handler.

I'd like to place a wager on #2.

Answer (score 1):

```
    socket.on('login', function (data) {
        login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
            if (success) {
                usernames[data.username] = socket.id;
                io.sockets.emit('login', {result: true, id: value});
            } else {
                io.sockets.emit('login', {result: false});
            }
        });
    });
```